# REST request in Apache failing with "client denied by server configuration"

Tags: apache, rest, tomcat

We have upgraded to Apache 2.x and Tomcat 7.x recently and seeing this issue.

Our Rest enabled Web services are deployed in Tomcat.

RESTful API's require hierarchical URI's that have nothing to do with directory structures on a filesystem. e.g. http://mycomp.com/product/123.

All the `GET` requests are working fine but when we try to use `PUT/DELETE/POST` etc, client is thrown out with `"403 Forbidden"` error, and Apache error.log shows : `"client denied by server configuration"`

I have checked httpd.conf file and it has `<Directory>` block with "Allow all" access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by updating `<LimitExcept GET POST>` element.